# spring-ws behind a Zuul proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws, netflix-zuul

I have a microservice (spring-boot) implementing a WSDL using spring-WS.
The plan is to access the WSDL through a gateway server, using Zuul.

Accessing from the Gateway: http//192.168.1.5:8080/integration/ws/test.wsdl

The Zuul route is configured at the Gateway:

```
integration:
  sensitive-headers:
  path: /integration/**
  url: http://localhost:9090
```

The WSDL is returned with the correct Port number (8080) but incorrect hostname. Also the prefix "/integration" is not returned.

```xml
<wsdl:service name="TestPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:TestPortSoap11" name="TestPortSoap11">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Even if I manually set X-Forwarded-For headers, the hostname never seems to change. [This I test without Zuul].  What am I missing in order to get Spring-WS working behind a proxy?  I have set remote_ip_header & protocol_header in Spring boot's application properties.

Answer (score 2):

Zuul actually strips the proxy prefix from the request before the request is forwarded by default. You can switch off this behaviour with `stripPrefix=false` like below for individual service. If you want for all routings then `zuul.stripPrefix=false`

```
application.yml
 zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      stripPrefix: false
```

Hope this will solve your issue.